# Total number of instances of single-digit numbers w/in two-digit numbers w/in same cell.

Tags: microsoft-excel

Our legacy payroll system reports each day of the month, i.e., 1 through 31, across a single row of cells, e.g., A1:AE1. Below each day, an empty cell or a two-digit number is reported. An empty cell means the employee was not at work at all that day. Since we operate on two back-to-back shifts, the system reports two-digit numbers. The two-digit number, not separated by a space, has no meaning as a whole; each digit must be interpreted separately. Each digit is limited to numbers 0 through 5; and can look like 22, 33, 50, 32, or 40. The 0 through 5 range is used to codify hourly pay rates. A 2 means $14/hour, whereas a 3 means $16/hour. It is the sum of all instances of each pay rate, 0 through 5, that I am trying to tally but have not been able to. The point of doing this is to find out how many shifts, not days, an employee worked at a certain hourly rate. These tallies would be reported to the right of column AE.

COUNTIF(A1:AE1,"*2*") tallies 2 for {..., 50, 23, 32, ...} -- Desired tally

COUNTIF(A1:AE1,"*2*") tallies 3 for {..., 22, 23, 32, ...} -- Hoping to get a 4

I have tried tinkering with SUMPRODUCT but haven't been very successful.

In the image below (not allowed to post because I'm a newbie), there are 2 instances of hourly rate 2 and 8 instances of hourly rate 3 between the 14th and 18th of November 2013, i.e., {23, 33, 33, 33, 23}. Although the COUNTIF formula used also reports 2 instances of hourly rate 2, it only reports 5 instances of hourly rate 3.

Comment: How about using two helper columns to split the two-digit numbers into digits and counting them?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SUBSTITUTE` to count within individual cells and then sum them up with `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A1:AE1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:AE1,"2",""))))
```

The above is to count the `2`. You can change the 2 to 3 to count the `3`s:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A1:AE1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:AE1,"3",""))))
                                                ^
```

`LEN(A1:AE1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:AE1,"3",""))` gives the number of each `3` in each particular cell.

The logic is subtracting the length of the cell without 3 from the length of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UDF  (User Defined Function), and use that to do the counting.
Instead of putting =COUNTIF(A1:AE1,"2")  in a cell, rather put =TALLYPAYRATES(A1:AE1,"2")

Press  View / Macros / ViewMacros

In Macro Name, type  TALLYPAYRATES,  and press Create.
Replace both lines with the following--

```
Function TALLYPAYRATES(rng As Range, sRate As String) As Long

    Dim nOccurs As Long
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim sCellRate As String

    nOccurs = 0
    For Each aCell In rng
        sCellRate = Format(aCell, "00")

        If Left(sCellRate, 1) = sRate Then
            nOccurs = nOccurs + 1
        End If

        If Right(sCellRate, 1) = sRate Then
            nOccurs = nOccurs + 1
        End If

    Next aCell

    TALLYPAYRATES = nOccurs

End Function
```

Then add something like the following in some cells

=TALLYPAYRATES(A1:F1,"2")

=TALLYPAYRATES(A1:F1,"3")

The following data ------- gives these results

22  33  50  32  40  counts      3   3

50  23  32  00      00      counts      2   2

22  23  32  00  00  counts      4   2

23  33  33  33  23  counts      2   8

Answer (score 0):

Another way is the following:

```
=COUNT(IF(VALUE(MID($A$1:$AE$1,SEQUENCE(2),1)) = COLUMN()-COLUMN($AF$1:$AF$1), VALUE(MID($A$1:$AE$1,SEQUENCE(2),1)), "a") )
```

It breaks each cell into two array elements and makes a full array of all of them. Then makes them values, not text. The `IF()` then checks each array element for a value and places a text character in the place of any that are not equal to it. `COUNT()` then counts the numerical values left, ignoring those text character elements.

What value is the `COLUMN()-COLUMN($AF$1:$AF$1)` calculation. It starts at 0 and rises to 5 as you copy and paste into the five cells so that it is in the range `AF:AK`.

(For whatever reason, I am not presently able to make it a `Spill` formula, so the copying and pasting is needed.)

The key element is the distinction `COUNT()` makes between values and text.

It looks long and messy, but one could dress that objection up via `LET()` or, if preferred or not available, Named Ranges.

*(Of course, in 2014 it would have needed CSE entry and `SEQUENCE()` would need replaced, probably with an array constant (`{0,1,2,3,4,5}`). This answer is not only meant to present a different way, but also one that uses more of post-2021's capabilities.*

*In some time period over the next year and a half, as the new text/array formulas are finally allowed to most of us, this will become trivial to do. But until then... and for legacy installations...)*